# Django-pagination: Accessing the page object after using {% autopaginate list %}

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using django-pagination to paginate lists for my Django site. At the top of my template, I'm using

```
{% autopaginate projects 10 %}
```

I want to display something like 'Showing 1 - 10 of 52 results'. I know it's easiest to do this with the page objects created by the template tag. The problem is that I don't know how to access it in the template context.

I tried to look through the source, and it looks like the tag loads it into 'page_obj' as you can see [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/source/browse/trunk/pagination/templatetags/pagination_tags.py#104), but I couldn't get it to work.

Showing `<span>{{ page_obj.start_index }}</span> - <span>{{ page_obj.end_index }}</span> of <span>{{ projects.count }}</span> results`

only displays: Showing - of **5** results

Comment: Seriously? I know this one should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

check out [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination)

just put:

```
      {% paginate %}
```

on the template after the {% autopaginate projects 10 %} tag.